# How to add on Click event on Collection View of Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a collection view of images in my Xamarin Forms Project. I want to add onClick event on images to navigate to the respective page of each image. I tried to find the solution and there is no definite answer for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a **TapGestureRecognizer** on Image .

#### in xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="xxx"
             
             x:Name="CurrentPage" //set name here  >
```

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                        ItemsLayout="HorizontalList">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>                   
                        <Image  
                               Source="{Binding xxx}" 
                               Aspect="AspectFill"
                               HeightRequest="xxx" 
                               WidthRequest="xxx" >

                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>

                                <TapGestureRecognizer  Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CurrentPage}, Path=BindingContext.ClickCommand}" />

                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>

                        </Image>
                        
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

#### in ViewModel

```
public ICommand ClickCommand { get; private set; }

INavigation Navigation;

public xxxViewModel(INavigation navigation)
{
  Navigation = navigation;

  ClickCommand = new Command(() => {

    // navigation.PushAsync(xxx);

  });
}
```

#### in ContentPage

```
public xxxPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   BindingContext = new xxxViewModel(this.Navigation);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution. It navigates only the main page. I don't know how to navigate the respective page.

Comment: You need to set  different page in method PushAsync .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT How do you get properties of the image? Like the url of the image item.